# Make variables from string words and attach them to bind_param and bind_result in PHP

Tags: php

There is my function:

```html
<?php
public function sql_limit_query($query,$type_params,$bind_res_params,$bind_param,$limit){
    $query = $query.$limit;
    $stmt= $this->connect()-prepare($query);
    $stmt-> bind_param($type_params,$bind_param);
    $stmt-> execute();
    $stmt-> bind_result($bind_res_params);
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    
}
?>
```

(For $limit I have other function from which I am taking Limit and Pagination buttons, depending on number of returned results, that is why I am not including it directly into the query;)

So how can I make that so if I pass `'title,id,carbohydrates,proteins'` in `$bind_res_params` to attach them as variables to `bind_result()` function...
And how can I make it also if I pass `$bind_param` as `'title,id'` to attach each to `bind_param()` function.

I have tried to use `call_user_func_array()`, but it didn't work..

Comment: Explode the string `$words = explode(',', $bind_res_params);` and iterate through the resulting array. However, if you're going to bind them, you will need to add placeholders in your query as well.

Comment: see [this example in the docs](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073)

Comment: Are those words column names? It yes, then those can't be bound. What do you expect the resulting query to be and what should it do?

Comment: You have a typo. Look here `$this->connect()-prepare($query);` it should be  `$this->connect()->prepare($query);`

Comment: How does passing `'title,id'` intended to work?  Are these the values you want to be put in (e.g. `'Title of item,1'`)?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think the only way to do it is by loop like you said,and execute 1 query per bind_param() variable.. which is not pretty efficient, but will do the work, something like that https://pastebin.com/KVeA00Di.I just saw your second comment. If you ask for words which I want to use in bind_param, yep they are just example columns, if I need bigger query with more than 1 parameter to bind. So there is nothing to be done, no loops,no anything to bind more than one parameter? ;(

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Thanks

Comment: @NigelRen  I wanted to pass those parameters in query which is something like:

Example:
SELECT title,id,carbohydrates,proteins from food_data WHERE id = ? and title = ? 

And of course after that i wanted to retrieve the results as $title,$id,$carbohydrates,$proteins variables, loop them and store in array, to use in future.